# Array of handles is not allowed C++

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, string-literals, cross-language

I'm having a issue translating a array of String^ that I'm receiving from a C# application. Why can I not create an array of String^? 
I'm fairly new to C++ so any help is appreciated.

```
public ref class Example
    {
        public:
            String^ Convert(String^ pointNames[], String^ outputPath)
            {

                std::string convertedPath = msclr::interop::marshal_as< std::string >(outputPath);
                std::string result = otherFunction(pointNames, convertedPath);

                return  msclr::interop::marshal_as< String^ >(result);
            }
    };
```

pointsNames[] is underlined as the error, with the message: Array of handles is not allowed.

What would be a better approach to send an array of strings from a C# application to C++?

Comment: A quick search suggests changing `String^ pointNames[]` to `WriteOnlyArray<String>^ pointNames` - Can you try that?

Comment: @Thebluefish I'm not sure I understand, I replaced String^ with WriteOnlyArray<String>^ but the compiler just says WriteOnlyArray is not a template, do I have to include some library?

Comment: It looks like this belongs under the `Platform` namespace - Taken from [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f0e968b2-5798-430a-8a00-d45c4a9ef1e0/pointer-to-a-c-array-of-hat-handles?forum=winappswithnativecode).

Comment: @Thebluefish okay that seems to work but how do I convert that to a string[] ?

Answer (score 4):

You tried to declare an unmanaged array type there, but you need a managed one to hold mananged types.

Declare the parameter as `array<String^>^ pointNames`.

Note: this is *not* `std::array`, it's [`cli::array`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts4c4dw6(v=vs.100).aspx), but when compiling with `/clr` then `using namespace cli;` is implied.

Comment: How would I make a cli::array to a string[] then?

Comment: Threre's no built-in method like `marshal_as` for this, you just need to write a loop and convert each string one by one.